# printf with %g and a correct double value prints irritating number - What could be the cause?

Tags: c, printf, double

Hi there I was hoping to find help here. I don't understand the following behavior. Please note that this is an exercise from The C Programming Language (4-4).

It is about the `double top(void)` definition in the `stack.c`. It should return the top of the stack as a double.

When I try to print it (with the command `p`) then the number format is not correct.
If I put the `printf(...)` in the top function itself then the format is correct.
I don't understand why that is.

I am using NetBeans 8.0.2 with default gcc compiler.

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXOP 100 /* max size of operand or operator */
#define NUMBER  '0' /* signal that a number was found */

int getop(char []);
void push(double);
double pop(void);

/* reverse Polish calculator */
main() {
    int type;
    double op2;
    char s[MAXOP];

    while ((type = getop(s)) != EOF) {
        switch (type) {
            case NUMBER:
                push(atof(s));
                break;
            case '+':
                push(pop() + pop());
                break;
            case '*':
                push(pop() * pop());
                break;
            case '-':
                op2 = pop();
                push(pop() - op2);
                break;
            case '/':
                op2 = pop();
                if (op2 != 0.0)
                    push(pop() / op2);
                else
                    printf("error: zero divisor\n");
                break;
            case '%':
                op2 = pop();
                if (op2 != 0.0)
                    push((int) pop() % (int) op2);
                else
                    printf("error: zero divisor\n");
                break;
            case 'p':
                printf("\t%.8g\n", top());
                break;
            case 'd':
                push(top());
                break;
            case 's':
                printStack();
                break;
            case '\n':
                printf("\t%.8g\n", pop());
                break;
            default:
                printf("error: unknown command %s\n", s);
                break;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

stack.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXVAL  100   /* maximum depth of val stack */

int sp = 0;
/* next free stack position */
double val[MAXVAL];
/* value stack */

/* push:  push f onto value stack */
void push(double f) {
    if (sp < MAXVAL)
        val[sp++] = f;
    else
        printf("error: stack full, can′t push %g\n", f);
}

/* pop:  pop and return top value from stack */
double pop(void) {
    if (sp > 0)
        return val[--sp];
    else {
        printf("error: stack empty\n");
        return 0.0;
    }
}

/* top: return top value from stack */
double top(void) {
    if (sp > 0) {
        return val[sp - 1];
    } else {
        printf("error: stack empty\n");
        return 0.0;
    }
}

/* swap two top values */
void swap(void) {
    if (sp > 1) {
        double t1 = pop();
        double t2 = pop();
        push(t1);
        push(t2);
    } else
        printf("error: stack (almost) empty\n");
}

/* clear the stack */
void clear(void) {
    sp = 0;
}

/* print the stack */
void printStack(void) {
    int i;
    for (i = sp - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        printf("%g ", val[i]);
}
```

getop.c

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUMBER  '0' /* signal that a number was found */

int getch(void);
void ungetch(int);

/* getop:  get next operator or numeric operand */
int getop(char s[]) {
    int i, c;

    while ((s[0] = c = getch()) == ' ' || c == '\t')
        ;
    s[1] = '\0';
    if (!isdigit(c) && c != '.' && c != '-')
        return c;
    if (c == '-') { // possible negative number
        if (!isdigit(s[0] = c = getch())) { // minus operator
            ungetch(c);
            s[0] = c = '-';
            return c;
        } else { // negative number
            s[0] = '-';
            s[1] = c;
            i = 1;
        }
    } else
        i = 0; // positive number
    if (isdigit(c)) /* collect integer part */
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
            ;
    if (c == '.') /* collect fraction part */
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
            ;
    s[i] = '\0';
    if (c != EOF)
        ungetch(c);

    return NUMBER;
}
```

getch.c

```
#define BUFSIZE 100

char buf[BUFSIZE]; /* buffer for ungetch */
int bufp = 0; /* next free position in buf */

int getch(void) /* get a (possibly pushed back) character */ {
    return (bufp > 0) ? buf[--bufp] : getchar();
}

void ungetch(int c) /* push character back on input */ {
    if (bufp >= BUFSIZE)
        printf("ungetch: too many characters\n");
    else
        buf[bufp++] = c;
}
```

Comment: "the number format is not correct". Please be more specific what you get and what you want.

Comment: What does the debugger display as stack contents? What gets printes by printf()``?

Comment: Please enable warnings. Does `main.c` know about function prototypes? Probably not, because you don't include anything except standard headers in `main.c`, which would lead to an implicit return type of ´int`. (Consider compiling in C99 or newer standards, which don't allow implicit function prototypes.)

Comment: `int top()` will be the implicit decl of the otherwise unheard of function in `main()` since you didn't provide a prototype. And an `int` is definitely not going to play well with when `printf` is expecting a `double`.

Comment: I see that you have prototypes at the top of `main.c` for most functions, but not for `top`. Please don't write the requires prototypes by hand. Create `stack.h`, which you then include from implementation `stack.c` and from client code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `main.c` does not know how `top` is defined. It decides on a default return value of `int`, which leads to undefined behaviour when printing it with a format designed for `double`. If you enable warnings, which you should, you'll get something like "Implicit declaration of `top`".

You have written the declarations of the stack functions `push` and `pop` at the top of `main.c`, but not the declaration of `top`.

Including the required prototypes by hand is not good practice. It is better to declare the interface of a compilation unit in a header file:

```
// stack.h
#ifndef STACK_H_INCLUDED
#define STACK_H_INCLUDED

void push(double f);
double pop(void);
double top(void);
void swap(void);

#endif
```

Include that header file from the code where you wish to use the interface. You will always have the correct and up-to-date version.

Include the header from `stack.c`, too, to ensure that the published interface and the actual implementation are consistent.

Comment: That was it. A really unnecessary beginner's mistake I think :-( Thank you for your explanation. Makes perfect sense. I switched on "show more warnings" on NetBeans, but I am not sure where to see them. Would someone have a tip?

Answer (score 0):

%g prints shorter of the two representations: f or e .
example: 
1) printf( "%g", 3.1415926 );
OUTPUT: 3.1515926

2) printf( "%g", 93000000.0 );
OUTPUT: 9.3e+07
Where scientific notation is most appropriate.